# Dividing django project into applications

Tags: django

**Edit 1**: Rewrote question, including more relevant information

I've been reading a lot on creating django applications that do a single thing and can be easily reused in different projects separately from one another.

Essentially I have an administrative tracking project that manages both projects and placements.  Both project management and placement management use similar data and therefor share a model.  However both are independent of each other and may have uses in one project but not another.  What would be the best way to organize these into different apps?

I've created an image with more details about the specific project in general including a simplified EER diagram, data types, and initial thoughts which can be found here: http://pasteboard.co/1weejc3V.jpg

---

**Edit 2**: Another thought...

Would creating a single management app which contains two sub-applications be a good way to do this? I.e. The management app hold the model which consists of the data that both placements and projects use.  One sub application contains the functionality for placements, the other contains the functionality for projects.  Is there any flaws with this idea, or simply better ways to go around it?

Comment: FWIW, I once read an article written by a guy who worked with Django for various clients all day long, and I remember distinctly he said, "as nice as the idea from the Django docs may be of having distinct, self-contained apps, I've never seen it in the wild." At work, some of our models and apps are thoroughly tightly coupled, and it's because _what they're modeling is too_. If they weren't deeply intertwined, they'd just be bad models.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I'm mainly concerned with reusability though.  In the case of project/placement management, many people wont need to keep track of placements what-so-ever, so being able to simply pull in the project app, without the extra bloat from placements would be nice.